# Two joins on same tables

Tags: php, sql, join

I am trying to show data by joining 2 tables:
[image]

In `users` table I have the equipment parts i.e. `tmn1` and `tmn2`.

In actual equipment table, I have the details for all equipment.
[image]

So when a user is logged based on TM1, TM2 numbers should be taken from the user's id and details corresponding to those in equipment table and needs to be showing. I tried using 2 sql joins on same table but its throwing an error. Any help would be appreciated.

For example user with id 1 is logged. The user has tmn1 as TS1234 and TM2 as TC1234 so in his account page the details of TS1234, TC1234 has to be pulled from 2nd table and needs to be shown.

```
 $queryEqipmentBought = "SELECT equipment.equipment_name, equipment.number_of_parts 
                         FROM equipment
                         RIGHT JOIN user_table ON  equipment.tm_number = user_table.tmn1
                         RIGHT JOIN user_table ON  equipment.tm_number = user_table.tmn2";
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below query...

```
$queryEqipmentBought="SELECT * FROM equipment 
RIGHT JOIN user_table ON equipment.tm_number IN (user_table.tmn1,user_table.tmn2) 
WHERE user_table.user_email = '".$user_email1."' ";
```

Comment: Easy and better one.

Comment: Yes because no need to do it complex for @Ram

Comment: @Ruchish Parikh Thanks. The errors are gone. But the result shows only TM1 results. TM2 is now shown. Am I missing any conditions. Thanks again.

Comment: Try to use LEFT JOIN @Ram

Comment: @ Ruchish Parikh thanks for your quick help. I will try that out and update you.

Comment: @RuchishParikh that worked. Now I wanted to make sure the user is logged in and show only the equipment user bought. So I have a session variable $user_email1 = "test@gmail.com";  and then modified query as

$queryEqipmentBought="SELECT * FROM equipment
          RIGHT JOIN user_table ON  equipment.tm_number IN (user_table.tmn1,user_table.tmn2) 
    WHERE user_table.user_email = $user_email1 ";

Its throwing an error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@gmail.com' at, do you have any idea.

Comment: @Ram , Please check answer I have edited with where query. You just need to concate it when using php variables with query. Please accept answer and click right if its work for you.

Comment: @RuchishParikh Worked perfectly And accepted the answer.  I cant give you a +1 as I dont have that right as I am yet to gain the reputation.Thanks again Ruchish.